# How to change the message box button content according to the language selected by user in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, localization, messagebox

I'm developing windows phone 8 application and this application should work in two languages English and Arabic.

**In some screens I'm showing the message box with some message and buttons(OK, CANCEL). 
When the application is in English the buttons content (OK and CANCEL) is displaying in English. It is fine.**

**But when the application is running in Arabic language, then the Buttons content is not displaying in Arabic.It is showing in English only**

How should I change the buttons content based on the language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Windows Phone toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) CustomMessageBox control.
It can be easily localized:

```
 CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
    {                
        Caption = "Do you like this sample?",
        Message = "There are tons of things you can do using custom message boxes. To learn more, be sure to check out the source code at Codeplex.",
        LeftButtonContent = "yes",
        RightButtonContent = "no",
        IsFullScreen = (bool)FullScreenCheckBox.IsChecked
    };
```

Comment: How should I show the above messagebox.  CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
                {
                    Caption = "",
                    Message = AppResources.SmsConfirmText,
                    LeftButtonContent = AppResources.OkText,
                    RightButtonContent = AppResources.CancelText,                    
                };
                CustomMessageBoxResult result = messageBox.Show(); Please tell me I'm getting the error at the last line.

Comment: Post here the error. Official sample is [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#PhoneToolkitSample/Samples/CustomMessageBoxSample.xaml.cs).

Comment: I'm getting this error. FullScreenCheckBox not found in the current Context.

Comment: Set it explictly to false and try ( `IsFullScreen = false` ). I think that you have no FullScreenCheckBox control at the page and this is from a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8, you have access to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameServices` which has a much more versatile message box you can use and no need to download a separate library.

```
IAsyncResult result = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(
    AppResources.SmsConfirmText,
    "",
    new string[] { AppResources.OkText, AppResources.CancelText },
    0,
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.MessageBoxIcon.None,
    null,
    null);

// Include following line if you want it to be synchronous
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

int? choice = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.EndShowMessageBox(result);
if(choice.HasValue)
{
    if(choice.Value==0)
    {
        // User clicked on the first button: AppResources.OkText
    }
    else if(choice.Value==1)
    {
        // User clicked on the second button: AppResources.CancelText
    }
}
```

Source: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Advanced_MessageBox_for_Windows_Phone